# Using AWK on macbook to do file bookkeeping

Tags: macos, awk, itunes

I'm kind of new to the mac & unix environment.. I'm trying to manage my itunes library files, which are pretty mixed up at the moment.

Specifically some of my albums were ripped twice - once in m4a, and once in mp3. Unfortunately, that means I have duplicates in iTunes. I want to delete the mp3's, but keep the m4a's. Not all albums have m4a's, so I can't do a mass delete of mp3's.

My thought is to use awk to search through the directories which have both m4a's and mp3's, and then delete the mp3's only in those directories.

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AWK. The following command uses `find` to find all the m4a files and feeds them to a shell command. The shell command substitutes "mp3" in place of the "m4a" at the end of the filename, checks to make sure the mp3 file exists, then deletes it.

```
find . -name '*.m4a' -exec sh -c 'f="${1%m4a}mp3"; [ -f "$f" ] && rm "$f"' _ {} \;
```

To try it out before you use it live, change the `rm` to `echo`.

Comment: as in, we've played this jinx game before.  I actually had `find . -type f -name "*.m4a" -exec bash -c '[[ -f ${1%.*}.mp3 ]] && echo rm $1' _ {} \;` first but decided to wrap it in a while loop for no particular reason at the last minute.   P.S. You don't use AlertBear do you?

Comment: @SiegeX: I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: if MAC uses GNU find, could use `+;` instead of `\;`.

Comment: @ghostdog `+` isn't going to work when `find` passes the file names as a single argument to the shell, at least not without being rewritten with a for loop over `$@`

Comment: @ghostdog74: SiegeX is correct and Macs use BSD-based tools. However, OS X `find -exec` does support `+`.

Comment: Right, `+` was added in the 2004 POSIX spec, it's actually not a GNU'ism like many people think.  RE: [Alertbear](http://www.alertbear.com/about.shtml), it's an RSS "reader" for Windows that runs in the background and throws popups when something is added to a feed you're following.  Just wondering what you were using since you seem to be on questions just as fast.

Comment: Its just me of course, since i dislike calling the shell for each m4a file i find (or am i seeing it wrongly?). well....if OP is fine with it, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do 
  [[ -f ${file%.*}.mp3 ]] && echo rm ${file%.*}.mp3
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.m4a" -print0)
```

Remove the `echo` if it works for you